# Совпадение имен

Tags: c++, конструктор, member

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что `Стандарт` говорит про следующую ситуацию:

```
class Object
{
    public:
    Object(const bool member) : member{member}
    {}
    private:
    bool member;
};
```

Если имя параметра совпадает с именем члена, способен ли компилятор разрешить эту ситуацию? Есть ли гарантии этого?

Судя по поведению `Visual Studio`, компилятор данную ситуацию разрешает. Но всегда ли так было?

Comment: да, всегда так и было, потому что в инициализаторах инициализируются только члены_ это и дает гарантию, что не будет никакой неоднозначности, но для удобства лучше избегать одинаковых имен

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061864/priority-between-local-variable-and-class-attribute-in-case-of-name-conflict/34062111

> 3.3.7  Class scope
>   4) A name declared within a member function hides a declaration of the same name whose scope extends to or past the end of
>   the member function’s class.

Перевод :

Имя, объявленное в функции-члене, скрывает объявление с тем же именем, область которого распространяется до или после конца класса функции-члена.

Проверка :

```
// g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -Wextra -Wpedantic initclassmem.cpp  -o initclassmem
# include <iostream>
class Object
{
    public:
    Object(const bool member) : member{!member},member2{!member2},member3{this->member}
    {}
    void print(){
      std::cout<<"["<<member<<","<<member2<<","<<member3<<"]";    }
    private:
    bool member;
    bool member2  ;
    bool member3  ;
};

Object  o2 {true};
Object  o {false};

int main() {
  std::cout<<"o=";
  o.print();
  std::cout<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"o2=";
  o2.print();
  std::cout<<std::endl; 
}
```

Результат :

```
> ./initclassmem 
o=[1,1,1]
o2=[0,1,0]
```

Первый элемент инициализируется аргументом, второй самим собой, третий с явным указанием переменной класса.

Comment: Это: `member2{ !member2 }` не является инициализацией(результат не определен)

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan В GCC Bugzilla я пытался мозги по пороть про это, но они никак не могут определиться в стандарте это или нет. Начальное значение должно быть false по стандарту.

Comment: не должно быть никакого начального значения. Эти обьекты занимают некоторую область памяти, где может быть  инициализирован любой бит, и только случайно они могут иметь нулевое значение.  Члены класса  не являются глобальными обьектами, чтобы инициализировались неявно.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Глобальные переменные сначала zero - инициализируются, прописываются в экзешнике эти нули. Затем при запуске программы вызываются конструкторы. Не зря же я впихнул эти переменные в глобальную видимость. Только для демонстрации вызовов конструктора объекта. При вызове конструктора все переменные объекта попадают в видимость, неважно как они были инициализированы.

Comment: Только для демонстрации сойдет, я имел ввиду общие правила...Запустил ваш код сейчас, и вот предупреждение копилятора: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning C26495 Variable 'Object::member2' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6)`....